# Is every elliptic curve isogeny over $\mathbb{F}_p$ separable?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I know that a isogeny $\varphi: E \rightarrow E^\prime$ has degree equal to its kernel if and only if the isogeny is separable.

I want to know if this always holds for elliptic curves over $\mathbb{F}_p$, with $p$ prime. If this isn't true I would like an example of a non-separable isogeny over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: The Frobenius map is a non-separable isogeny that has trivial kernel but degree $q$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Frobenius endomorphism $F:E\to E$ given by $F:(x,y)\mapsto(x^p,y^p)$
when $E$ is in Weierstrass form is inseparable.

Comment: Is there a non-separable isogeny such that $p$ doesn't divide its degree?

Comment: @José no, because any (finite) inseparable extension of fields has degree divisible by the characteristic

Comment: @José To further hunter's response. If $\varphi$ is inseparable then $d\varphi:T_e E\to T_{e'}E'$ (where this denotes the tangent spaces at the identity) is zero (else $\varphi$ is etale and thus generically etale). But, note that since $\varphi\circ\varphi^\vee=[\deg\varphi]$ one sees that $d\varphi\circ d\varphi^\vee$ is multiplication by $[\deg\varphi]$. From this, it's easy to see that if $\deg\varphi$ is not divisible by $p$ then $d\varphi$ must be invertible, and so $\varphi$ separable.